# Can I attend a short training course for medical professionals on a UK standard visitor visa?

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, study

What category of visa do I need to come to the UK to attend a short training course, training being for licensing exam? There will be no patient interaction, we practice on dummy heads and teeth. Will a standard visitor visa allow this or a would a short term study visa be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are coming for education, it'd be the short term study visa.

But if you reach out to the course organizer, I'm sure they would have a more concrete answer.